# How can I disconnect this brass fitting on my kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

I'm replacing at least the handle of a kitchen faucet (possibly the whole thing). Its the type where the spout is standalone, then there's a separate hot/cold combo handle, then a separate sprayer.

I removed the hot/cold waterline connections coming into the handle, but the line coming out of the handle going to the spout has a strange connection I'm not familiar with. The flexible line connects to a brass looking ferrule connected to a black plastic tee (with the other tee connections going to the faucet and to the sprayer).

I twisted the ferrule, but it just spins. I also tried twisting the line piece going into the ferrule, but couldn't get it to turn. I was being cautious, as I didn't want to break any of the lines, since I may try to keep the spout piece. Any idea what this connection is, and how to remove?

The piece I’m referring to is on the left in the picture, with the steel braided hose coming into it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The braided hose is attached to the black plastic fitting with a push-fit connector.
The locking part is inside the brass 'ferrule' on the end of the hose, and to release it you need to pull the light-grey plastic ring back in towards the ferrule (away from the black plastic fitting).
The hose should then just pop off as you're doing that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this is a push fit connector, you need to remove a clip of there is one, then push in the white portion, while pulling out on the hose. The top hose looks like a locking pin that needs removed first.

Comment: Yah, it’s the piece that you refer to as the locking pin that’s my question. So that should just come off then continuin to rotate the ferrule? Is the locking pin just the ferrule, which is threaded on the inside?

Comment: I would guess that on the side arm one removes the clip and this allows the tubular brass fitting to be pushed (or possibly twisted) into the space formerly occupied by the clip which would unlock the hose and allow it to be pulled off.

Comment: That is how it looks to me. I doubt it is threaded, it is most likely a push pull once the clip is removed or pressed in. If it were threaded I'd be surprised.